# Is __repr__ supposed to return bytes or unicode?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, unicode, repr

In Python 3 and Python 2, is `__repr__` supposed to return bytes or unicode?  A reference and quote would be ideal.

[Here's some information](https://portingguide.readthedocs.io/en/latest/strings.html) about 2-3 compatibility, but  I don't see the answer.

Comment: My guess is that it shouldn't return unicode, since repr() is supposed to be used for the programmer (not the user), and some consoles don't support unicode.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The type is `str` (for both python2.x and python3.x):

```
>>> type(repr(object()))
<class 'str'>
```

This has to be the case because `__str__` defaults to calling `__repr__` if the former is not present, but `__str__` *has* to return a `str`.

For those not aware, in python3.x, `str` is the type that represents unicode.  In python2.x, `str` is the type that represents bytes.

Comment: `str` is unicode in Python3 and bytes in Python2. I believe the OP is looking for those details

Comment: @cowbert -- No, `str` is `str` in both.  Python3 has no unicode type (just as python2 has no bytes type).  Semantically, python3's `str` is the functional equivalent to python2.x's `unicode` if that's what you're trying to say...

Comment: @mgilson the OP is clearly asking if repr returns an object with a bytes or unicode representation and is clearly wondering about the Py2 vs Py3 difference. In Py3, `str` is a unicode object.

Comment: It could be worded better.  The type is `str` in both, but they mean completely different things...!

Comment: Also of interest: the accessors for both `__str__()` and `__repr__()` require the return type to be set to `str`. In Py3k I tried overriding both `__str__()` and `__repr__()` to return `b''` and all of `print()` (which calls `__str__()`), `str()`, and `repr()` (which calls `__repr__()` will yield a `TypeError: ... returned non-string (type bytes)`.

Answer (score 1):

It's `str` in both languages:

```
Python 3.6.4 (default, Dec 21 2017, 18:54:30) 

>>> type(repr(()))
<class 'str'>

Python 2.7.14 (default, Nov  7 2017, 17:59:11) 
>>> type(repr(()))
<type 'str'>
```

(There's a tuple in there.)